# Quick edit destroys CKEditor formatting... any way to avoid it?

Tags: wysiwyg, entities

Quick edit doesn't bring up CKEditor buttons, and clears immediately all previous formatting (like numbered lists), which can lead to serious data lost, in my case.
Is there any patch to have Quickedit SKIP those textareas at all, while allowing it to interfere in those more simple fields?
Using 7.x-1.5 module version, Drupal 7.41
thanks

Comment: Have you changed anything under admin/config/content/formats ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch between text formats and not have your code erased go to:

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]